# Fragment android:visibility in xml layout definition

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

How does it works? I have layout like below:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/search_form_fragment"
        android:name="FragmentClass"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/result_list_fragment"
        android:name="FragmentClass"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="gone" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Note the second fragment has `android:visibility="gone"` and indeed it is not visible on screen. But this code:

```
boolean bothVisible = firstFrag.isVisible() && secondFrag.isVisible();
```

returns `true`, which was not expected by me. I wonder if using `android:visibility` is correct cause I could not find any information about it in documentation.

Comment: Are you initializing (getting reference to) `firstFrag` and `secondFrag` correctly?

Comment: Yes, I get reference by `getFragmentById()`.

Comment: As in `firstFrag = getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.search_form_fragment);` and `secondFrag = setFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.result_list_fragment);`?

Comment: Yes, that`s how I get references to Fragments.

Comment: Ok, beats me then. I just wanted you to make sure that there isn't some silly mistake in the code somewhere. :) Well, good luck.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Per the [Fragment source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/app/Fragment.java), `isVisible` is defined as:

```
 final public boolean isVisible() {
    return isAdded() && !isHidden() && mView != null
            && mView.getWindowToken() != null && 
               mView.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE;
}
```

I.e., it is attached to the activity, it is not hidden (via the [FragmentTransaction.hide](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#hide%28android.app.Fragment%29)), the view is inflated, the view is attached to a window, and the **interior view of the Fragment** is `View.VISIBLE`.

I believe the issue is that in order to inflate your fragment, the system creates a layout to hold the Fragment's view. It is that view that you are setting to `View.GONE`, not the interior view that the Fragment creates.

I might suggest changing your condition to be:

```
findViewById(R.id.result_list_fragment).getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried doing this

XML

```
<FrameLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/lateral_login_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:visibility="gone"/>
```

Code

```
LoginFrag = LoginFragment.newIstance();     
FragmentTransaction LoginTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
LoginTransaction.replace(R.id.lateral_login_frame, LoginFrag);
LoginTransaction.commit();

Log.d("visibility", String.valueOf(LoginFrag.isVisible()));
```

And my log was:

```
05-09 19:07:54.236: D/visibility(3483): false
```

From android [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#isVisible%28%29), isVisible() Return true if the fragment is currently visible to the user. This means it: (1) has been added, (2) has its view attached to the window, and (3) is not hidden.

Maybe you haven't added the fragment just yet? from the code I can't tell. Hope this helps.

Comment: Ok, but you add fragment programatically. I was wondering how android:visibility works on <fragment> tag in xml.

Comment: Then I think ianhanniballake answer is what you're looking for.